# How can I set different sessions to be used for different users?

Tags: x11, login, session

Is it possible to write a script that runs at login which will automatically run a custom session for a given user? I would like to have my personal user account login to my normal, entire KDE desktop, and then I have another home theatre user that will boot into a single fullscreen application, Plex, by way of writing a custom session - with no desktop environment accessible until I logout and back in as my personal user.

Comment: You'll have to modify/configure the display manager: It's the program responsible for starting the desktop environment after login. I'm not sure if kdm/lightdm/sdmm (whatever your system uses) can be configured to do that easily. If not, you may need to switch to another display manager.

Comment: @dirkt I have created a custom `.desktop` session that I can manually launch at login. This session has no desktop environment and simply launches the Plex app alone. I am now looking to automatically launch this session when a certain user logs in, and launch the regular KDE Plasma session for all other users

Comment: Which display manager are you using? On what distribution?

Comment: @Gilles I am using Manjaro KDE

Comment: With which display manager (the program where you type your username and password, and often get a choice of session type)? KDM?

Comment: SSDM, it is the default login manager (?) that comes with KDE.